# Attempting to fire click events on google map markers from external react component

Tags: reactjs

[image: Screen shot]
My [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/infallible-wright-nmo45) the code for which I take no credit as it comes from this great [post](https://janosh.io/blog/google-maps+react-hooks) displays a google map with some markers and below it, a list of links. with an onClick handler, I'm trying to trigger the marker's

```
window.google.maps.event.trigger
```

I believe I need to make the markers I create, global so I was trying to do so using the useState hook. Every time I have done so it has gone into an infinite loop.

Comment: where does addMarkers get called?

Comment: Please add the full component

Comment: A code sandbox would be very helpful here.

Comment: Appreciate comments. Will put together sandbox

Comment: Have now added codesandbox and abbreviated the question as have comments in the code. Hope you can shine a light on this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am on the same dilemma and would greatly appreciate of any solutions for this. Thank you